# Can I use any "wallet" to store Litecoins?

Tags: wallet, litecoin, dogecoin

I have a doge wallet, can I use it to collect litecoins? Or do I need to specifically get a litecoin wallet to receive payments for hashing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any wallet is based on the particular set of cryptographic functions used for a single cryptocurrency. If you tried to send dogecoins to a litecoin wallet address, the transaction would not be valid because the dogecoin blockchain is only a record of dogecoin transactions and the litecoin blockchain is only a record of litecoin transactions.

Comment: Cheers, NReilingh.

Answer (score 0):

they are different. you will lose your LTC if you send to doge adress. I advise you use the official site of LTC to find the official wallet. many people lost theirs coin to third party wallet.